# Ubuntu - Disable or Remove default VNC server

Tags: vnc, vino

if you install ubuntu then there is automaticaly a possibility of connecting to the computer remotely, it is **disabled** by **default** but is there any way of **removing** this possibility ? in other words: can i remove that **Destkop Sharing** application somehow? so **you will not be able** to **turn it on** ever **again**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo apt remove vino` will remove it.

But someone could reinstall it.

Comment: thanks , yes sure you can reinstall it but this is what i was looking for, once  again thanks